# How a VIEW works?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, data-structures

**Here is the scenario:**

I have several Posts tables and one Votes table. How can I prevent inserting non-existing post_id (in Posts tables) in the Votes table?

```
// Posts_1                  // Posts_2                  // Posts_3
+----+---------+            +----+---------+            +----+---------+
| id | content |            | id | content |            | id | content |
+----+---------+            +----+---------+            +----+---------+

// Votes
+----+---------+
| id | post_id |
+----+---------+
```

For doing that I have created a `Post_Index` table which combines all the posts to one single place and gives it like this:

```
// Posts_Index
+----+---------+------------+
| id | post_id | post_table |
+----+---------+------------+
```

Plus a FK like this: `post_id -> votes.id`.

---

**Here is my question:**

Now I want to know, Is it better to I create a `VIEW` instead of that `TABLE` *(`Posts_Index`)* ? Because the posts will be increase all the time and I need to update that table every time *(using a `TRIGGER` on the each `Posts` table to insert a new row in ``Post_Index` after insert in itself)*

---

**Why I asked this question:**

Because I read in documentation which VIEW will be created according to the logic every time when a statement is executed that references the view. So, it I think it needs to a lot of processing.

---

**Now, What I want to know:**

In my case, a `VIEW` is better or a `TABLE` and multiple `TRIGGER` on each Posts-table for create a new row in that table after insert in each Posts-table?

Comment: "How can I prevent inserting non-existing post_id (in Posts tables) in the Votes table?" -- I do not understand what you are trying to say.  Please rephrase.

Comment: @RickJames I'm trying to say: assume `id = 100` is not exist in none of those Posts tables (`Posts_1`, `Posts_2`, `Posts_3`). Now assume one user (like a hacker) sends a vote for the post with `id=100`. Well, What I want is showing a message to that user (hacker) containing: "that post you are voting is not exist"

Answer (score 0):

You could declare the `votes.post_id` column as a foreign key to `posts.id`. See the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) for additional details.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, there is multiple `Posts` tables. So, how can I declare a FK to `posts.id`. that `posts` in the FK is refers to which one of those `Posts` tables?

Comment: @Shafizadeh, I misread that part of your message. The easiest solution would be to have a single Post table, but you might have good reason not to do it that way.

One possible solution would be to declare a trigger running before insert on the post tables, where you can implement the validation that you need, and either let it proceed or raise an exception.